# How can I get a purchase check in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am not able to figure out how I can get the following result with one MySQL Query:

I have two tables:

**shop_items**

```
| id | description | price | active |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+
|  1 | product_1   |   5   |   1    |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+
|  2 | product_2   |  10   |   1    |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+
|  3 | product_3   |  15   |   0    |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+
```

**inventory_items** (the shop_items a user purchased)

```
| id | item_id | user_id | active |
+----+---------+---------+--------+
|  1 |    2    |    1    |   1    |
+----+---------+---------+--------+
|  2 |    1    |    1    |   0    |
+----+---------+---------+--------+
```

I want to see all `shop_items` where `active = 1` including a row called `purchased` = `0 or 1` based on `inventory_items` -> matching `user_id` (where user_id = something) and `active = 1`

**Example output based on the data from above tables** ->  `where user_id = 1`:

```
| item_id | price | description | purchased |
+---------+-------+-------------+-----------+
|    1    |   5   |  product_1  |     0     |
+---------+-------+-------------+-----------+
|    2    |  10   |  product_2  |     1     |
+---------+-------+-------------+-----------+
```

What query do I need for this output?

Please note: I only need the result from ONE user_id which I can change within the query :)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please improve your question by putting what you've tried so far and what the results have been.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test

```
SELECT shop_items.*, COALESCE(inventory_items.active, 0) purchased
FROM shop_items
LEFT JOIN inventory_items ON shop_items.id = inventory_items.item_id
                         AND user_id = 1
WHERE shop_items.active = 1
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you so much!